# Golang wrong http resquest header

Tags: go, http-headers, go-gin

I'm building 2 apis. One make request to another.

To call the api that receives requests, we need to pass a X-Token Header. I'm doing this with Golang

```
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        },
    },
}

req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://localhost:8086/v2/example", nil)
if err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"Error": err.Error()})
}
req.Header.Add("accept", "application/json")
req.Header.Add("content-type", "application/json")
req.Header.Add("x-token", "a2e63ee01401aaeca78be023dfbb8c59")

resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

In the other API, i get the http header with [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) like this:

`token := c.Request.Header.Get("x-token")`

I dont know why my header arrives with another value and no X-Token. Thanks!

Result of `fmt.Printf("%+v", c.Request.Header)`:

```
map[User-Agent:[Go-http-client/1.1] Referer:[https://localhost:8086/v2/example] Accept-Encoding:[gzip]]
```

I don't know where is my *x-token*, *accept* and *content-type* headers....

**IMPORTANT**

- If i make a request with *x-token* header on Postman to the requested API i get the right header.
- If i change the request address on the API that makes requests, e.g [httpbin](https://httpbin.org/headers), i get the right header too....

Comment: what is the output of fmt.Println(c.Request.Header) ?

Comment: @Apin i edited the question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helo, guys! i found the solution....

I don't know why yet... but i think golang don't handle *no trailing slash* url's....

https://localhost:8086/v2/example
is different of
https://localhost:8086/v2/example/

That was my problem....

I just copy and past the golang generated code of postman... and that was the "biggest" difference....

Thanks mr. Postman...